# How do you modify a nodejs module variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

(This is probably a very silly question since I'm just beginning with nodejs, nevertheless I can't understand how this works. Let me know what is missing in my question, I'll correct.)

I'm trying to use the npm package [likely](https://www.npmjs.com/package/likely).

in my server.js file I have thus written this

```
var Recommender = require('likely');
```

in likely.js you can find variables like these:

```
var DESCENT_STEPS = 5000; // number of iterations to execute gradient descent 
var ALPHA = 0.0005;       // learning rate, should be small
```

I would like to modify these variables inside my server.js file.
I believe the way to do that is adding this after the require()

```
Recommender.DESCENT_STEPS = 9999999999;
```

but that doesn't seem to change the value that is defined in likely.js and that is actually used by the model. (by running the model I can see it doesn't work since so much steps should take forever and the processing time doesn't change at all)

Can I only do this by modifying likely.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify them programmatically because likely.js only uses the local variable values instead of the current value of the exported versions of the same variables. So if you wanted to change those values you currently would need to edit likely.js. You might want to submit a pull request to that project's repository that makes the code use the exported value (e.g. `module.exports.DESCENT_STEPS`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publicize these variables to be viewable by server.js.

```
var object = {
    DESCENT_STEPS = 5000;
    ALPHA = 0.0005; 
}
module.exports = object;
```

Now it can be viewed and modified in server.js.
`Recommender.ALPHA = 'new value';`